# Error with Spring BOOT

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am running a simple desktop application using Spring BOOT. Below is the error stack:

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
 at com.pb.relay.RelayDesktopApp.main(RelayDesktopApp.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
 ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:426)
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f9a7b9e6.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$34(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f9a7b9e6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$26f1a4a6.invoke(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f9a7b9e6.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
 ... 15 common frames omitted

Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
```

My Main class:

```html
package com.pb.relay;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableAsync
@EnableRetry
@EnableScheduling
public class RelayDesktopApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(RelayDesktopApp.class);
            app.setHeadless(false);
            app.run(args);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println(t.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what is cause of this error: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping'.
I have NO where any @EnableWebMvc annotaions.

Any feedback ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

@EnableAutoConfiguration also does auto configs for WebMvc, so pls exclude this as well :-

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Answer (score 5):

By default `SpringApplication`, will deduce whether or not you're building a web application based on what's on the classpath. If you have some Web-related dependencies on the classpath but aren't building a web application, you can explicitly tell `SpringApplication` that you don't want a web application:

```
app.setWebEnvironment(false);
```

This is preferable to explicitly disabling Web-related auto-configuration as it means you don't need to know what those auto-configuration classes are and lets Spring Boot take care of it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The same idea than Avis but in configuration file:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

I use springboot and added following to application.properties file to overcome this exception:

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration,